# How to get value inside vuetify chip

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue application where I am displaying information inside of vuetify chips. When I want to click on a specific chip I want the console to log the value inside it. I tried accessing the array which the information originate from but I am getting an undefined error. Could someone look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it?

html:

```
 <v-chip-group
                v-model="selection"
                active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4"
                mandatory
            >
              <v-chip
                  v-for="(time, i) in dateTimeArray"
                  :key="time"
                  :value="time.startTime+' | '+time.endTime"
                  @click="pushSelected()"
              >
                {{ time.startTime +" : "+ time.endTime }}
              </v-chip>
            </v-chip-group>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  name: "MeetingAdminComponent",
  data : ()=>({
    singleSelect: false,
    selection: "",
    dateTimeArray:[], 
    availableTimes: [
    ],



  }),

  created() {
    this.getAvailableMeetingTimes()
  },

  methods:{

    getAvailableMeetingTimes() {
      var pageURL = window.location.href;
      var lastURLSegment = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/voterAvailableTime/findBy", {

        params: {
          meetingName: lastURLSegment,
        }

      })
          .then(response => (this.availableTimes = response.data)
          )
    },

 getTimesFilteredByDate() {
      var pageURL = window.location.href;
      var lastURLSegment = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var selectedDate = this.selectedDate
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/voterAvailableTime/find", {

        params: {
          meetingName: lastURLSegment,
          date: selectedDate
        }
      })
          .then(response => (this.dateTimeArray = response.data))
    },

    pushSelected(){

      console.log(this.availableTimes.startTime+ " " + this.availableTimes.endTime)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: In addition to @Boussadjra's answer, you can also pass just the index of the item and access the item from your original array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the current `item` as parameter to the method :

```
          <v-chip
              v-for="(time, i) in dateTimeArray"
              :key="time"
              :value="time.startTime+' | '+time.endTime"
              @click="pushSelected(item)"
```

in methods:

```
  pushSelected(item){

      console.log(item.startTime+ " " + item.endTime)
    }
```